# Calculate combinations of positioning alphabet in N available positions in order

Tags: combinatorics

I have a sorted list of items (e.g. the alphabet). How can I calculate the number of combinations that these items can be placed in a set of N possible positions (where N is more than the items in the first list), *while keeping the items in order*, but potentially having empty positions.

E.g. A, B could be placed in 3 slots as follows:
A, B, empty; 
A, empty, B;
empty, A, B

Regards

Comment: If you have $m$ sorted objects ($m=26$ for the English alphabet), they can be placed in $\binom{N}{m}$ positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have $N$ slots and $M$ letters, with $N\ge M$.  (In your example, $N=3$ and $M=2$.)  Then once you choose the slots that will be filled by the $M$ letters, the positions of the letters themselves are determined (because they must be in order) and the positions of the $N-M$ blank spaces are completely determined (because they go in the remaining slots).  So the answer is therefore  $$\binom NM = \frac{N!}{M!(N-M)!}.$$

(If you are not familiar with the notation, leave a comment.)